# Testing shell script in windows

Tags: windows, shell

I need to write a simple shell script that will run on a Linux box, and I want to test it on my windows machine.

Looking all over I find solutions like Cygwin. But I don't really need a Linux environment -- I just want to do some light testing. Is there a simple solution that doesn't require heavy duty installations, for just this one small task?

Comment: If you can do it online, I would create a free shell account somewhere like this http://www.cjb.net/shell.html and test it on SSH client

Comment: That's a great solution, I'm on it right now. Thanks! (and if you create an answer I'll definitely accept it.)

Comment: Glad it can help. I used it when preparing a script for a dd-wrt router (it got Busybox with all the goodies) and don't want to keep rebooting the router when my faulty script kill the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do it online, I would create a free shell account somewhere like this cjb.net/shell.html and test it on SSH client

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will not be possible without some "heavy duty installation" as most scripts rely on UNIX-System tools which are by default not available in a windows environment.

If you want to keep your system clean, try a virtual machine. You can set up **VMWare** Player  or **Virtualbox** with some e.g. Ubuntu ISO in less than 10 Minutes and it won't influence your system. (Apart from the VMWare installation).

There are also some pre-built VMs available:

http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads/

Best of luck

Ben

P.S.
IMHO Cygwin is a helpful and handy tool to have installed on a Windows box.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. But the solution in the comment to my question is great for me.

Comment: That's ok. Nonetheless, if you find my answer useful, please vote up-

Comment: I think you could use Cygwin.